# deferred constraint checking

Tags: sql-server, constraints

Currently In our database design we have an circular reference between two entities.  In other words, we have foreign keys in each table that reference each others primary key.  In order to insert records in these tables we need to perform a deferred constraint checking.  Is this possible in SQL Server 2008?  I know Oracle DDL has special syntax for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deferrable Constraints in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998095/deferrable-constraints-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no native way to do deferred constraint checking in SQL Server.

Likely your best option is to insert a NULL value into the foreign key column in the first table until the second record is inserted, and then as part of the same transaction, update the foreign key column in the first table.

I'm interested - what is the business reason for your circular reference?  It's definitely an extraordinary requirement.

Also have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955671/dealing-with-circular-reference-when-entering-data-in-sql), on the same topic.

Comment: @Aaron.  We have a recursive reference between synonims of the same product.

Comment: @Igor: Then likely what you want is to store the product-name in a separate table, with a 1-to-many relationship between the product-info and product-names.  Deferred Constaints Checking would be very helpful in cases where you want to swap or reorder a unique key, though (such as an *"Ordering"* column)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your circular FK constraints are there to ensure a one-to-one relation for table extension purpose?

---

#### Case 1: The data insert is done as some sort of data fix

During the data insert, you will need to disable the contraints (Assuming you use explicit named contraints in your FK definition, which is a good practice).

E.g.,

```sql
-- Prep - Disable the FK constraints

ALTER TABLE dbo.TableMain
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_TableMain_TableExtension_ID
 
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableExtension
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_TableExtension_TableMain_ID
GO  

-- Do your insert stuff in both tables, ensuring data integrity
...
...
...
GO

-- Re-enable your constraints

ALTER TABLE dbo.TableMain
CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_TableMain_TableExtension_ID
 
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableExtension
CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_TableExtension_TableMain_ID
GO
```

---

#### Case 2: One-to-one Master / slave table structure

If somehow you would allow a user to add to one table and the other table acts as a slave, then obviously you don't want the constraints to be disabled / enabled frequently.

Instead, you should consider only to have FK from the slave table to the master table, but to ensure 1 to 1, also define the FK as the PK in the slave table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Master
{
   i_masterId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
   , ... other columns
}

CREATE TABLE dbo.Slave
{
   i_masterId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
   , ... other columns
   , CONSTRAINT [FK_Slave_ToMaster] FOREIGN KEY (i_masterId) REFERENCES dbo.Master(i_master),
}
```

And if you wish to automatically create `dbo.slave` always, define an `INSERT` trigger on the `master` table.