# How to deal with mutually dependent inserts

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

I have a model that defines mutually recursive tables:

```
Answer
  questionId QuestionId
  text

Question
  text
  correct AnswerId
```

What do I need to do to actually insert a question?  I need to know what the correct answer is first.  But to insert an answer, I need to know what question it answers.

I'm running Postgres, if it matters.

The DDL is:

````sql
CREATE TABLE answer (
  id integer NOT NULL,                 -- answer id
  text character varying NOT NULL,     -- answer text
  question_id bigint NOT NULL          -- question id
);

CREATE TABLE question (
  id integer NOT NULL,                 -- question id
  question character varying NOT NULL, -- question text
  correct bigint NOT NULL,             -- correct answer
  solution character varying NOT NULL  -- solution text
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY answer ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('answer_id_seq'::regclass);

ALTER TABLE ONLY answer
  ADD CONSTRAINT answer_question_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES question(id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY question ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('question_id_seq'::regclass);
ALTER TABLE ONLY question
  ADD CONSTRAINT question_correct_fkey FOREIGN KEY (correct) REFERENCES answer(id);
```sql
````

Comment: I don't feel the recursion here. This looks like a straight forward foreign key relationship, unless when dealing with Question.QuestionId 1, has an AnswerId of 2, which in turn has a QuestionId of anything other than 1?

Comment: @Jaaz: It's a model for multiple choice tests.  Each question will have, say, 4 answers.  Only one of them is correct.  The question knows which one is correct, and the answers know which questions they point at.  I can't insert a question unless I know what it's answer id is.  I can't insert an answer unless I know what its question id is.

Comment: lol that seems so silly. You can't insert a question without knowing the correct answer and you can't insert an answer without knowing the question? Can you redesign this sillyness at all, or are you stuck with it?  The correct answer should not be stored on the question record...

Comment: Ah, ok. This might be easier to answer, then, with full DDL statements from your tables. For example, is Question.QuestionId a SERIAL column, or just an INT Id that can be assigned by the application?

Comment: @Twelfth: that seems more like a limitation of the database engine than the model.  The answer *should* be stored with the question, because it is a property of the question.

Comment: @nomen - not at all...a database should never enforce conflicting requirements like a question requires an answer (not null) prior to any answer being entered (it's not a database limitation, it simple logic). Correct answer should either be on the answer record (correct/incorrect being a property of the answer), or a third table that maps questions to correct answers, or the correct answer must allow nulls so a question can be entered then answers, then the update of the question record.

Comment: @Twelfth: They're not conflicting requirements.  The problem is that the database doesn't have a way to insert both requirements "at the same time" (in the context of a single insert).  At least that I know of.  Hence my question.

Comment: @nomen - I think thats true of every database engine...no? The second you split this into 2 tables you made the simoultaneous insert option impossible. I guess a 4th solution would be to combine the tables and flatten out the entire relation so it is just one insert. and a 5th solution...drop the relation, insert, rebuild the relation.  WIsh I had a better answer

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but I think "deferred constraints" and manually working with the IDs would work (reserving question ID in advance, and deferring the FK constraint that refers to it so you can insert the answers first).

Comment: Hmm....looking further into the documentation, there's a way to do it, but it's not pretty, per se. Can you, in your application, guarantee that the correct answer will be inserted first out of a set of answers? Can you also guarantee only 1 connection doing inserts at any time?

Comment: @Twelth I agree with the OP: the data is not conflicting once it is in place. The intermediate state, which incorrectly allows a question with no correct answer, or an answer without a question, is not part of the model. It may need to exist as a technical limitation, but constraining against it is a valid aim.

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, I've gotten the clarify on there...once he has the data in there, the constraints work...it's just getting there that is his issue. Got tons of work arounds, but none of them are really a solution. Curious what Jaaz Cole has with the correct answer inserted first.

Comment: Finally remembered the right term to search for: "circular references" is the common name for this kind of situation. Which leads to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955671/dealing-with-circular-reference-when-entering-data-in-sql Not sure at a glance if any of the answers will run directly on Postgres, but the principles and techniques should apply.

Comment: Heh, answers there are pretty much the same...Oracle has a special defer constraints command, microsoft you simply allow nulls...

Comment: @Twelth I don't think the different answers reflect capabilities of different software as much as different expertise of those answering. Deferred constraints are definitely not unique to Oracle.

Comment: @IMSoP: The suggested duplicate doesn't have satisfying answers. I think I provided something better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you enter question and answer in a **single statement** with a [data-modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING), you do not even need a `DEFERRABLE` FK constraints. Not to speak of actually making (or `SET`ting) them `DEFERRED` - which would be a lot more expensive.

#### Data model

First I cleaned up your data model:

```sql
CREATE TABLE question (
   question_id       serial PRIMARY KEY
 , correct_answer_id int  NOT NULL
 , question          text NOT NULL
 , solution          text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE answer (
   answer_id   serial PRIMARY KEY
 , question_id int  NOT NULL REFERENCES question
 , answer      text NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE question ADD CONSTRAINT question_correct_answer_id_fkey
FOREIGN KEY (correct_answer_id) REFERENCES answer(answer_id);
```

- Don't use the non-descriptive "id" or "text" (also a basic type name) as column names.
- Put integer columns first for space efficiency. See:

  - [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468)
- `bigint` was uncalled for, `integer` should suffice.
- Simplify your schema definition with [`serial` columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860).
- Define primary keys. PK columns are `NOT NULL` automatically.

#### Solution

After delegating primary key generation to sequences (`serial` columns), we can get auto-generated IDs with the `RETURNING` clause of the `INSERT` statement. But in this special case we need *both* IDs for each `INSERT`, so I fetch one of them with `nextval()` to get it going.

```sql
WITH q AS (
   INSERT INTO question
          (correct_answer_id              , question, solution)
   VALUES (nextval('answer_answer_id_seq'), 'How?'  , 'DEFERRABLE FK & CTE')
   RETURNING correct_answer_id, question_id
   )
INSERT INTO answer
      (answer_id        , question_id, answer)
SELECT correct_answer_id, question_id, 'Use DEFERRABLE FK & CTE'
FROM   q;
```

I *know* the name of the sequence (`'answer_answer_id_seq'`) because I looked it up. It's the default name. If you don't *know* it use the safe form [@IMSoP provided in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813000/sql-how-to-deal-with-mutually-recursive-inserts/24816197?noredirect=1#comment38533095_24816197):

```
nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('answer', 'answer_id'))
```

#### `DEFERRABLE` or `DEFERRED` constraints?

[The manual on `SET CONSTRAINTS`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#id-1.9.3.85.9.4)

> `IMMEDIATE` constraints are checked at the end of each statement.

My solution is a *single* statement. That's why it works where two separate statements would fail - wrapped in a single transaction or not. And you'd need `SET CONSTRAINTS ... DEFERRED;` like [IMSoP first commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813000/sql-how-to-deal-with-mutually-recursive-inserts/24816197#comment38519912_24813000) and [@Jaaz implemented in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24814737/939860).
However, note the disclaimer some paragraphs down:

> Uniqueness and exclusion constraints that have not been declared
> `DEFERRABLE` are also checked immediately.

So `UNIQUE` and `EXCLUDE` need to be `DEFERRABLE` to make CTEs work for them. This includes `PRIMARY KEY` constraints. [The documentation on `CREATE TABLE` has more details](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#id-1.9.3.85.9.4):

> Non-deferred Uniqueness Constraints
>
> When a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint is not deferrable, PostgreSQL
> checks for uniqueness immediately whenever a row is inserted or
> modified. The SQL standard says that uniqueness should be enforced
> only at the end of the statement; this makes a difference when, for
> example, a single command updates multiple key values. To obtain
> standard-compliant behavior, declare the constraint as `DEFERRABLE` but
> not deferred (i.e., `INITIALLY IMMEDIATE`). Be aware that this can be
> significantly slower than immediate uniqueness checking.

We discussed this in great detail under this related question:

- [Constraint defined DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE is still DEFERRED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032272/constraint-defined-deferrable-initially-immediate-is-still-deferred)

Comment: I don't see the reason for the additional CTE only to call `nextval()`? A simple `insert into ... values (nextval()...` would work just as well.

Comment: On a point of pedantry, just because your answer is so careful with other best practices: since you're not manually creating the sequence, you should not be hard-coding its name, so need `nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('answer', 'answer_id'))` instead of `nextval('answer_answer_id_seq')`. (My rule of thumb being "if you didn't name it, don't assume you know its name".)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: True, the first CTE was overkill. I simplified accordingly.

Comment: @IMSoP: Good point, too. My example assumes that I *know* the name of the sequence. If you don't, your alternative is the sure way.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter But you fixed the schema so that you *don't* know it. If I run `CREATE SEQUENCE answer_answer_id_seq;` followed by your recommended SQL, it will fail, because the `serial` in the table definition will be forced to pick a different name. Given you went so far as to move the int columns to save disk space, *not* using a proper lookup for the sequence seems like a flaw in an otherwise very careful answer.

Comment: @IMSoP: I just have to look it up *once* to know it. It's not going to change. Alternatively, we can create the constraint with an explicit name to be sure. And you are right, that it was a bit sloppy. So I added a pointer to your comment.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Not if you plan to save this schema definition for deployment in multiple environments. What is the advantage of *not* using the lookup function?

Comment: Point is shorter / simpler code and not to further complicate an already complex answer. There are always so many considerations one could add. I feel like I am doing too much of that already in my answers.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Well, if you use the robust form, you don't even need to explain it: as far as the reader's concerned, they will (rightly) assume that's just how you get the underlying sequence for a serial column. As it is, you've *added* complexity by explaining the assumption you've made.

Comment: @IMSoP: Also true. I think this is solved properly by pointing to your comment now.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I still see no reason not to edit the query to use the best-practice approach (just as you edited the OP's schema not to use columns called `id` and `text`, etc), because I see no reason to ever write code that doesn't do so. However, I'll "agree to disagree" if you're set on your current wording.

Comment: @IMSoP: Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help with this answer.  I must admit that, because I'm tied to a specific framework, I didn't implement some of your advice.  But the deferred constraint worked great.  I knew there had to be a way to get the DB to "always" (atomically) respect my domain constraint.

Comment: This is a really nice approach and would even work if I inserted multiple rows with multiple generated ids at once! However, I'm currently facing a problem with using this on identity columns where [apparently one needs extra permissions on the sequence to use `next_val()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57188959/1048572), is that expected?

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, the current role needs the `USAGE` or `UPDATE` privilege on the sequence to call `nextval()` on it. (Or be the owner or a superuser.) `UPDATE` or `INSERT` privilege on the owning table is not enough, though the implicit use of the attached sequence is granted. The sequence of an `IDENTITY` column is more of an implementation detail and not supposed to be used separately in normal operation. So you need `GRANT USAGE ON tbl_col_seq to my_role;` first. The sequence of legacy `serial` columns is more detached: there you need separate privs on the sequence even for `INSERT`.

Comment: @Bergi: If you can't get the owner to grant you the necessary privs on the sequence, but you have `INSERT` and `SELECT` on the table, an awkward workaround would be possible: `BEGIN; INSERT INTO tbl DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING id; -- take note of generated number! ROLLBACK;` You may have to provide actual values for `NOT NULL` columns without default, etc. Not recommended. Stuff for a question really, not a comment. ;)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Ok thanks for the confirmation, I can do the `GRANT`s no problem but I was really surprised there's an "implicit privilege" when "implicitly using" the sequence through inserts.

Answer (score 1):

I would insert into question, with a null correct AnswerId.  Then I would insert into Answer, and finally I would update Question and set the correct answerId.

Comment: Except that `correct_answer_id` is defined `NOT NULL` for some reason. And it can be cheaper.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Ah.  That's frustrating.  You could always disable the constraint temporarilly but I think Erwin's answer is sufficient.

Comment: Disabling the constraint temporarily requires privileges and takes out an exclusive lock on the table. No good for multi-user environment.

Answer (score 1):

I went looking around after seeing the DDL. Consider a function for your call to insert a question with correct answer, and one to add (false) answers to a given question. The structure of the first function allows the application to pick up the anonymous returned record for the questionID, and use it for subsequent calls to the second function, to add false answers.

```
CREATE FUNCTION newQuestion (questionText varchar, questionSolutionText varchar, answerText varchar, OUT questionID integer) AS $$
  BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
    SET CONSTRAINTS question_correct_fkey DEFERRED;
    questionID := nextval('question_id_seq');
    answerID := nextval('answer_id_seq');
    INSERT INTO question (id, question, correct, solution) values (questionID, questionText, answerID, questionSolutionText);
    INSERT INTO answer (id, text, question_id) values (answerID, answerText, questionID);
    SET CONSTRAINTS question_correct_fkey IMMEDIATE;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
  END;
$$
CREATE FUNCTION addFalseAnswer (questionID integer, answerText varchar) AS $$
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO answer (text, question_id) VALUES (answerText, questionID);
  END;
$$
```

I've not written SQL for PostGreSQL in a long while, so I hope all is in order here. please let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: There is no problem with concurrency or rollbacks here, because nextval() will never give the same answer twice, even in simultaneous transactions. However, your insert into `question` still violates the foreign key constraint: *you* know that you're about to insert an answer with that ID, but the DBMS does not. At the time that insert runs, there is no such row, so the constraint is violated.

Comment: Agreed, it was a piece I missed as I was looking for the syntax again. Thanks for the heads up.